Error: Cannot find module 'node:events' on mssql npm package
When we are importing the mssql line in server side, the app crashes.

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'

Repeatedly tried installing and uninstalling node modules
checked mssql npm package issues.
When we are importing the mssql no error should come.

What version of NodeJS are you using? Seems like it could be something before NodeJS 14.

Too old node.js
